# Sending Images from C++ to Java | convert Stream to suitable Java Datatypes

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, opencv

I want to send openCV Images via UDP Socket to a Java Server (run with GWT). How can I convert those cvFormats to java-workable datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

I once had to work on something similar to this, what I did was to serialize the raw binary data of the images and send it via UDP. At the other end I re-created an image with the server understandable type.

Don't forget that with GWT you could also send URLs of your images (say on the image source server). So you would have a dynamic URL only generated when you need to display it at the client side.

Comment: I try it with a Java Applet.. It works! Just have problems with the UDP Max-Data-Package-Size. Do you know a good method to split up Images into several data packages?

Comment: You should ask this to another question to stackoverflow!! I suppose you could try around 1k. I don't know the answer to this one. Good luck!